# Watchdog reports many spammy looking page not found warnings

Tags: drush, log-messages

Periodically, I like to run the following command to see what kind of activity and errors are going on with our website in real time.

```
drush ws --tail --full
```

1. Every second or so, there is a page not found error, but the pages are things that have absolutely nothing to do with the content of our website, following our Drupal URL format. Our site has been migrated a few times and may have old content from a long time ago, but again, this content doesn't relate at all to our subject material. Does anyone know what might be happening or if this is normal?
2. How do I stop the command from running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much every site online is being scanned by bots looking for security holes. The more popular the site, the more common this is. They don't necessarily follow links from the site itself, and even on Drupal sites you'll see requests for paths like "/wp-admin".

And you can exit via Ctrl-C.

Comment: Interesting. Here is an example: [ 17692704  27/Oct 16:05  warning  page not found  10-fastest-growing-mobile-apps-and-10-facebook-apps-year]. This page never existed but spam bots looking for security holes somehow generate this URL?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a spambot that tried posting that article and is seeing if it was successful. If you look up the IP it came from you may find more information.